# Testing has_many with shoulda-matchers using rspec3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, shoulda, rspec3

I'm trying to use rspec3 for the first time with a new app. I've defined two simple models:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :matches
end
```

When I access these models from the console, I can create the associations and store them in the DB as expected. But, when I try to run a spec to test this, it doesn't seem to work:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Article do
   it { is_expected.to have_many(:matches) }
   # it { should have_many(:matches) }
end
```

I tried running both the `isexpected` version and the `should` version of the test, but in both cases, I get the following error:

```
> ./bin/rspec spec/models/article_spec.rb
Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
F

Failures:

  1) Article should have many :matches
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to have_many :matches }
       expected #<Article:0x007fa14c276f38> to respond to `has_many?`
     # ./spec/models/article_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'

Finished in 0.09484 seconds (files took 0.63853 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/article_spec.rb:4 # Article should have many :matches

Randomized with seed 24636
```

Here are the relevant dependencies in Gemfile.lock:

```
rspec-core (3.0.4)
  rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
rspec-expectations (3.0.4)
  rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
rspec-mocks (3.0.4)
  rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
rspec-rails (3.0.2)
  rspec-core (~> 3.0.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 3.0.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 3.0.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
rspec-support (3.0.4)
spring-commands-rspec (1.0.2)
rspec-rails (~> 3.0.0)
spring-commands-rspec
...
  shoulda-matchers (2.7.0)
shoulda-matchers
```

It seems like it should be pretty straight forward. Am I doing something wrong that's causing me to get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to running the binstub created when installing Spring:

```
./bin/rspec spec/models/article_spec.rb
```

Apparently this does not work quite the same way as running the executable installed by RSpec, which is simply:

```
rspec spec/models/article_spec.rb
```

Comment: Interesting thought, but unforunately, I get the same exact error when I do it that way. Also worth noting that with rspec2 I never had to define subject explicitly to be able to use the association matchers in this fashion.

Comment: Ouch, you are correct, I forgot how shoulda-matchers works. I'll delete this response, but could you add the version of Rails and RSpec? I have your code working on Rails 4.1.5 and RSpec 3.1.5

Comment: Both the error and the rspec versions are in my original question. The rails version is 4.1.4.

Comment: Aha. Try `rspec` instead of `./bin/rspec`.

Comment: Wow, that was it. I auto-generated bin/rspec using the spring stub generator to let rspec run through spring. So, now the question is what's happening differently when I use the bin script. If you update your answer, I'll go ahead an accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the root cause is but I just got the same problem - with both bin/rspec and rspec.
I managed to get it working for rspec, but not bin/rspec.

I had to add `require 'shoulda/matchers'` to the spec file as well as rails_helper.rb to get the test to pass. This passed once, after which I could remove it from the spec file and the test passed. Strange and un-satisfactory fix.